# OWIN With Multiple OIDC Auth Configurations

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, owin, openid-connect

My application is Asp.Net 4.7.2 Framework MVC.  I want to have three OWIN OIDC Auth configurations registered and be able to choose from them.

```
OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions oidcOptions1 = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _oktaMvcOptions.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = _oktaMvcOptions.ClientSecret,
                Authority = _issuer,
                RedirectUri = _oktaMvcOptions.RedirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                RedeemCode = true,
                Scope = scopeString,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = _oktaMvcOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
                SecurityTokenValidator = new StrictSecurityTokenValidator(),
                AuthenticationMode = (_oktaMvcOptions.LoginMode == LoginMode.SelfHosted) ? AuthenticationMode.Passive : AuthenticationMode.Active,
                SaveTokens = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = BeforeRedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = SecurityTokenValidatedAsync,
                    AuthenticationFailed = _oktaMvcOptions.AuthenticationFailed,
                },
            };

OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions oidcOptions2 = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions{...};

OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions oidcOptions3 = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions{...};
```

In the Startup.cs, the Configuration looks something like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions1);   
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions2);   
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions3);
}
```

They are all OpenIdConnect types. When I call the challenge:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
```

How do I tell the challenge to use the oidcOptions2, or oidcOptions3?  How can I specify which one to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind - pretty easy:

```
OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions oidcOptions1 = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("first")
{
...
}
```

Then:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge("first");
```